# how to inject a service in Ember App with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ember.js

I am following this guide:
https://v4.chriskrycho.com/2018/typing-your-ember-update-part-1.html

Here I have a service, which only have one function findAllContacts:

```js
export default class ContactPicker extends Service {
  findAllContacts(): Promise<Contact[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(getContact());
  }
}

declare module '@ember/service' {
  interface Registry {
    'contact-picker': ContactPicker;
  }
}
```

and a phonebook component:

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import Computed from "@ember/object/computed";
import ContactPicker from '../services/contact-picker';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
export default class PhonebookView extends Component {
  contactPicker: Computed<ContactPicker> = service('contact-picker');

  didInsertElement() {
    let contacts = this.contactPicker.findAllContacts(); //error
  }
};
```

but I got typescript error when call this.contactPicker.findAllContacts():
**Property 'findAllContacts' does not exist on type 'ComputedProperty'.ts(2339)**

how to inject service with Typescript?

Comment: Have you tried `contactPicker: ContactPicker = service('contact-picker');`?

Comment: Type 'ComputedProperty<ContactPicker, ContactPicker>' is missing the following properties from type 'ContactPicker': findAllContacts, get, getProperties, set, and 16 more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import ContactPicker from '../services/contact-picker';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class PhonebookView extends Component {
  @service declare contactPicker: ContactPicker;

  didInsertElement() {
    let contacts = this.contactPicker.findAllContacts(); //error
  }
};
```